# JCheck box when placed in JTable cell not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I am a newbie to Swings

Can some on please help me

**I have a scenario:**  in which I placed `JCheck` boxes in the 3rd column of `JTable` by overriding its column class to return Boolean for the 3rd column.

So it appears as though we have check boxes in the 3rd column of the table...... lately I discovered that the table's list selection event gets fired only based on the "cell focus" in which the check box is present but not the check box itself.

i.e if the focus is on a particular cell (of 3rd column), the toggling of check box in the cell does not fire the event....

Am I missing some thing......

Comment: 1) The renderer used in table cells is a single instance that is used to paint the cells.  That means that things like buttons and check-boxes do not behave as they normally would. 2) *"Am I missing some thing......"*  A `?` key?  Please fix that sticky `.` key while you're at it.

Comment: I'd start by having a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), pay close attention the section on cell editors

Comment: What you have done is already existing in the API. Please go through tutorials of JTable. And before posting please try some example and show us the code where you are getting problem.

Answer (score 2):

> in which I placed JCheck boxes in the 3rd column of JTable by
>   overriding its column class to return Boolean for the 3rd column.

- [see Oracles JTable tutorial, to try code examples from tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [Boolean value  represents JCheckBox in JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

> i.e if the focus is on a particular cell (of 3rd column), the toggling
>   of check box in the cell does not fire the event....
>
> Am I missing some thing......

- [have to override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)